# Magento 1.9 : How to get Image on Product page -> 2columns-left.phtml?

Tags: image, column, magento1.9.2.3

I want to display my below image on product page left side,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEZDN.jpg

I just added directly into 2columns-left.phtml,

```
<div class="col-left sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-3">

                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?><br/>
                                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
                                          ->setBlockId('free_shipping_banner_pdp')->toHtml();?> 
                                </div>
```

Is my work recommend?

Comment: instead use catalog_product_view.xml
and override view.phtml in your module or theme. Than it is right

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang after added lines on catalog_product_view.xml,  then what i need to do in view.phtml.

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('free_shipping_banner_pdp'); ?>

Comment: Please check full answer below

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang may i know path of the catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Please chek updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Full answer, this is the correct way.

Path : app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\catalog.xml

catalog.xml

```
<block type="cms/block" name="your_block_id_1_name" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>your_block_id_1</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
```

Path : app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('free_shipping_banner_pdp'); ?>
```